# Export report error

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Exporting my Crystal Report is no longer working in my .Net web application. I get the following JavaScript error:

> unreachable code after return statement

Comment: can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Like this one, just posting a question nobody respond when someone tried to fix.